# Timestamp Conversion from "1592621463" to actual timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
{"publish_timestamp": "1592621463"}
```

"1592621463" getting timestamp like this through JSON object, how can I convert it into proper timestamp

Comment: What timestamp format do you want? Can you put this into a running python program with example input? If you want a traditional `time.time` value, its just `int("1592621463")`

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying and now working. Also please provide more details regarding the date format you want to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by proper timestamp you mean, actual date and time
You can do this using datetime

Try this,

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1545730073
dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print("dt_object =", dt_object)
```

Output

```
dt_object = 2018-12-25 09:27:53
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import datetime
js = {"publish_timestamp": "1592621463"}
js['publish_timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(js['publish_timestamp'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

---

```
{'publish_timestamp': '2020-06-20 08:21:03'}
```